# Events vs Observer pattern

Tags: java, c#, oop, events, design-patterns

Let's suppose: we have one object of interest and multiple objects interested in this object (its state for example). When object of interest changes in some way, others want to know about it.

**First approach**

It looks like classic problem that is solved by Observer Pattern. When object of interest changes it invokes methods on objects that are subscribing the event. Simple.

**Second approach**

Define an event in object of interest, on change, raise this event. Others will listen to this event and call their methods on it.

One obvious difference is that the object invoking method is different. But, why we should use one instead of the other approach?

I know these concepts, but I am looking for deep understanding of a problem.

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between Observer Pattern and Event-Driven Approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439512/difference-between-observer-pattern-and-event-driven-approach)

Comment: Observer pattern can work well across network to invoke method remotely, which is ideal use case, though events are suited more for in-process execution, they cannot span across network

Comment: There is roughly no difference between the two because when you "raise this event", what you do is you notify all the observers and call a method on them to tell them about the event. The only difference with a sophisticated event based system can be that there might be a 3rd party involved that distributes the event and handles observer registration. But it's still fundamentally an observer pattern

Comment: Stack overflow is not the place to talk about the pros and cons of patterns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few thoughts on the topic since asking the question:

I find the problem rather opinion based, but there are some pros and cons of both approaches:

Event-based approach is easier to amintain in my opinion:

```
public class Observable
{
    public event Action<object, object> OnStateChange;

    public void Event()
    {
        // do something
        // choose appropritate args
        OnStateChange.Invoke(null, null);
    }

    /* versus ************************************************/
    Observator[] observators;
    public void InformObservators()
    {
        foreach (Observator observator in observators)
            // choose appropritate args
            observator.UpdateState(null, null);
    }
}

public class Observator
{
    public Observator(Observable observable)
    {
        observable.OnStateChange += UpdateState;
    }
    /* versus ************************************************/
    public void UpdateState(object arg1, object arg2)
    {

    }
}
```

As we can see, `Observator` pattern won't differ much in two approaches, but `Observable` class will have simplier method informing about change, i.e. `Event` method, which is easier to maintain in my opinion than `InformObservers` from the second approach.